# Why is the C# SerializedAttribute is sealed?

Tags: c#

I was trying to create an attribute that implies `[Serializable]` but I noticed that this `SerializableAttribute` class is sealed.

In Java it was possible to create an interface (say, `MyInterface`) that is inherited from `Serializable` interface and so all the subclasses of `MyInterface` would also be serializable, even its sub-sub classes would be so.

Let's say I am creating an ORM and I want customers to annotate their entity classes as `[DatabaseEntity]` but in order to make sure that entities are serializable, I also need to ask them to attribute their classes with extra `[Serializable]` which does not look quite compact and neat.

I am wondering why `SerializableAttribute` class is **`sealed`** and why has **`Inherited=false`** which implies that subclasses of serializable class will not be serializable unless it is explicitly stated. What motives are behind these design choices?

Comment: You don't need `serializable` to make a class serializable. It is only used by BinaryFormatter. Other serializer can happlily serialize your class for ex, xmlSerializer, DatacontractSerializer, DatacontractJsonSerializer, JavascriptSerializer etc.

Comment: But I want my class to be return `true` from `myObject.getType().IsSerializable` at the same time. If you think so, please add your method as an answer.

Comment: What do you need `myObject.getType().IsSerializable`. Every class is serializable(nothing to do with the `serializable` attribute) by default.

Comment: Ahmet, if you simply want a marker that says "serializable", then implement ISerializable and test for it's presence. I dunno, maybe you have some classes you want to allow serialization for and some you don't and you want a convenient way to tell the difference.

Answer (score 4):

The SerializableAttribute is only used by the BinaryFormatter. If you are writing your own serialiser then don't worry about.

The `sealed` keyword is applied to the attribute not the class associated with the attribute.  It is saying that the SerializableAttribute cannot be subclassed.

The `BinaryFormatter` uses an opt-in model.  Any class (or subclass) must specify that it is serializable.  This why the `Inherited=false` is used.

Comment: So does C# have a compile-time error mechanism for non-serializable members of `[Serializable]`-tagged classes?

Comment: There is `[NonSerializable]` for fields/properties.  Also, a class can implement `ISerializable` to get down and dirty.  Again, this is only for the BinaryFormatter.

Answer (score 1):

It's suggested best practice that *all* .Net attributes should be sealed, [according to Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182267%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> The .NET Framework class library provides methods for retrieving custom attributes. By default, these methods search the attribute inheritance hierarchy; for example `System.Attribute.GetCustomAttribute` searches for the specified attribute type, or any attribute type that extends the specified attribute type. **Sealing the attribute** eliminates the search through the inheritance hierarchy, and **can improve performance**. [my emphasis]

So `[Serializable]` is sealed because it's quicker for .Net reflection to check the attributes. The cost is that you can't inherit and extend `SerializableAttribute`.

You can make your own un-sealed attributes if you want (you'll get code analysis warnings though).

This gets a little confusing with how attributes are used in inheritance for the classes that they apply to. It's probably best to use an example:

```
[Serializable]
public class A
{
    public int SimpleSerialisableProperty { get; set;}
}

public class B : A
{
    public C ComplexReferenceProperty { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class D : A
{
    public bool AnotherSerialisableProperty { get; set;}
}
```

You asked why `SerializableAttribute.Inherited = false` and this is why:

- Class `A` is marked as `[Serializable]`, and it is.
- However class `B` inherits `A` and extends it with properties that are not serialisable. If .Net tries to serialise `B` it will encounter an error.
- That `Inherited = false` tells .Net that just because `A` has been marked as `[Serializable]` not every class that inherits it will be serialisable too.
- Now class `D` inherits `A` and is serialisable, so it gets its own `[Serializable]` attribute.

Finally, in terms of design attributes are a great way of *extending* behaviour (nice UI editors in property grids, etc). However they are terrible at *enforcing* it. If you need your customers to implement their entity classes in a particular way then an `abstract` base class or an `interface` is a much better way to go. If you make it an attribute then you're basically letting them know that `[Serializable]` is an option that you can handle either way.

Answer (score 0):

Serialization is not a magic thing and you don't need any attribute to serialize an object. It is a  process of writing your class' properties and fields to a stream (and attributes are only directives to serializers about how to behave while outputting an object).

See this over-simplified serializer code which totally ignores all attributes including `NonSerializable`

```
object obj = yourObject;

var props = obj.GetType()
               .GetProperties()
               .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.GetValue(obj, null));

string serializedText = String.Join("\n",
              props.Select(kv => kv.Key + "=" + kv.Value ?? kv.Value.ToString()));
```

Above code, for example, would give

```
IsEmpty=False
X=3
Y=5
```

for `object obj = new Point(3,5);`

Deserialization process would be to read these values and set the properties back accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

Put the [Serializable] attribute on top of the class you want serialized. Serialization is opt-in process. You have to manually do that for each class you want serialized. There are bunch of other keywords.